# Angular template mysteriously shows only certain {{expressions}}

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using Angular JS v. 1.2.26 and I've spent hours trying to figure out why I cannot get certain expressions to appear in the view.

A complete, minimal, example is below (or jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/s_d_p/ztzprLb3/1/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var screen_id = '430732';
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/scripts/vendor/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      var tsApp = angular.module('tsApp',[]);

      var screenCtrl = tsApp.controller('screenCtrl', function($scope) {

        $scope.columns = [null,[null,{"name":"","id":"583","column":1,"order":1,"display_class":"static-text","block_agency":"static-text","block_mode":"static-text","custom_param":"","custom_body":"<b>This demo screen is brought to you by TransitScreen.com</b>"},{"name":"U St NW+ 17th St NW","id":"591","column":1,"order":2,"display_class":"masstransit","block_agency":"metrobus","block_mode":"bus","stops":[{"agency":"metrobus","mode":"bus","name":"U St NW+ 17th St NW","vehicles":[{"agency":"metrobus","mode":"bus","name":"U St Nw + 17th St Nw","full_route":"96","short_route":"96","destination":"Capitol Heights Station","predictions":[9,42],"direction":"Eastbound","vehicle_number":0,"logo":"","display_route":"96","longname":"96","route_class":"bus_metrobus","destination_class":"bus_metrobus","longname_accessible":null,"prediction1":9,"prediction2":42,"units":"MINUTES"},{"agency":"metrobus","mode":"bus","name":"U St Nw + 17th St Nw","full_route":"90","short_route":"90","destination":"Anacostia Station","predictions":[10,39],"direction":"Southbound","vehicle_number":1,"logo":"","display_route":"90","longname":"90","route_class":"bus_metrobus","destination_class":"bus_metrobus","longname_accessible":null,"prediction1":10,"prediction2":39,"units":"MINUTES"}],"walk_directions":"","walk_minutes":null,"arrow_svg":null}]}]];

      });//end screenCtrl
      screenCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

    </script>

  </head>
  <body class="screen-body total-cols-1" ng-app="tsApp">

    <div class="page-holder" ng-controller="screenCtrl">
      <div class="col" id="col-1">
        <div ng-repeat="block in columns[1]">
          <div ng-include="'/public/scripts/block.html'"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the contents of `block.html`:

```
<div ng-switch on="block.display_class">

  <div ng-switch-when="masstransit">

    <table>

      <div ng-repeat="stop in block.stops">

          <div ng-repeat="vehicle in stop.vehicles">

              <h2>Test 1</h2>
             {{ stop.mode }} 
             {{ block.display_class }} 
             {{ vehicle.vehicle_number }}

            <tr class="" id="">
              <td class="">

                <h2>Test 2</h2>

                 {{ stop.mode }} 
                 {{ block.display_class }} 
                 {{ vehicle.vehicle_number }}

              </td>

            </tr>

          </div><!-- ng-repeat -->         

      </div><!-- ng-repeat -->

    </table>

  </div> 

</div><!-- end ng-switch -->
```

Which outputs this...

[image]

Test 1 shows the expected values twice (because there are two items in the loop). Then in Test 2 there is only one iteration and *only* the middle value appears.

Comment: You need to add a complete block of code. Not sure why you are mixing TR and DIV. TR can only contain TH and TD. Is you TR inside a TABLE?

Comment: @doogabides yes of course. The `<div>` block is ONLY for testing purposes because the problem seems connected to the surrounded tag (see update #1 above). The code above is not the entire page. Just the relevant snippet from within an entire page of markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not identified in your code above. There is nothing wrong with ng-repeat in a TR or TD. It is more likely something is wrong in your controller or somewhere else in your code.

I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h7L1vnsp/) which shows an example of displaying data as near the data structure in your question as I could guess. It works fine.

```
<table ng-controller="myCtrl" border=1>
 <tr ng-repeat="stop in block.stops">
  <td ng-repeat="vehicle in stop.vehicles">
      <dl>
          <dt>Mode:</dt><dd>{{ stop.mode }}</dd>
          <dt>Class:</dt><dd>{{ block.display_class }}</dd>
          <dt>Number:</dt><dd>{{ vehicle.vehicle_number }}</dd>
      </dl>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT** 
I fixed your jsfiddle to work. [See edit 2 here](http://jsfiddle.net/ztzprLb3/2/) You can't expect Angular to work properly on malformed HTML. You cannot wrap TRs in DIVs like that. Even if Angular works who knows how some browsers might treat it. You might have data popping out after the table. Table rendering is one of the parts of HTML that is fairly strict.

Comment: I don't understand it either. What kind of issue in the controller are you thinking? I know the data is correct because I'm able to print the same value right next next to the table on the same page.

Comment: Like I said, without more of the code it's impossible to guess. Have you used chrome or firefox debug tools? Check console for errors, use inspector to view the contents of the output html to see if maybe something weird is there. Maybe the text is there but some html formatting is causing it not to display. All guesswork without an example of the failing code.

Comment: No errors in the console. The markup looks a bit weird, but I'm a bit new to Angular and I'm not used to some of the markup that gets add/removed when the directives are processed. I'll take a closer look and try to carve out a minimal example.

Comment: A new clue: the inner loop only runs once even when there are multiple vehicles

Comment: I updated the question with a minimal example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I edited your fiddle to work. Please accept this as the answer since clearly the issue is in the way you are trying to format your data. If you really need some other layout, use ONLY divs, no table. Then you can use CSS (maybe bootstrap) to layout the divs the way you want. I think that's the way designers prefer, but personally I have always liked tables.

Comment: AHA! I thought the `ng-repeat` element was just a wrapper, like the `{` and `}` in a for loop, so I didn't realize it was invalidating the markup. Thanks for your help!